# RequireJS + NodeJS returning XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'http' No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, jssip

Im trying to use JsSIP, but when I use the RequireJS to enable require in the client side CHROME returns:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/videochat/videonodejs/scripts/jssip. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Its all in localhost, so what could be the origin problem? I do have the port number in my URL, could that be it?

Comment: It's not "all localhost"; it's different ports.

Comment: use CORS to talk across domains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jssip request is on port 80 the app is on port 3000.  Those are not the same origin, per the same-origin policy.

Comment: Since i can't change my server port to 80, I was looking into http://jssip.net/documentation/0.5.x/getting_started/, but no documentation on how to change the port for JsSIP, any idea how? BTW, thanks for the remarkable fast answer ^^.

Comment: Never used jssip before, but allegedly you can set the URI yourself: http://jssip.net/documentation/0.5.x/api/ua_configuration_parameters/

Answer (score 0):

The server needs to specify the allowed origins in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Often times this value is set to `'*'` so it captures all client origins, or it is set to a white-list of allowed origins. This is defined in the server code and is required for ay API that handles cross-domain requests.

Look into `CORS` configuration for your application if adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header doesn't work.  If it doesn't work, you may eventually need to look into "pre-flight" requests.  They are an initial request sent to the server to determine server support for the upcoming request, and it's HTTP method is `OPTIONS`.  So, if you handle the server code, you will need to add 'OPTIONS' to the list of allowed methods, so you can handle that pre-flight request and thereby inform the browser that it should continue and send the real request to the server.....  I believe you can disable this behavior in chrome by launching with a command line flag (which i think is `--disable-web-security`).  Hope this is able to help you some.